# Create grayscale masks in Blender like Gimp

Tags: masking

I want to create an image only with highlights in Blender using the following method:

Image -> increase lightness = Image 2

Image 2 -> covert to black and white = BW-Mask

apply BW-Mask to image 2 like in Gimp to get Image 3 than contains only highlights and the rest of the image is transparent.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is to multiply the image by a variable using the **Converter** --> **Math node** (This will automatically convert to BW).

Then you use the **Converter** --> **Set alpha node** while using the same image as the mask.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Omar a lot for answering so fast. Your input was very  helpful.
My initial intention is to create a basic HDR effect on a movie by increasing the highlights.
Now I have created tow versions of the input image: one with more highlights and the other with more shadows. 
I created masks according to your description to filter the images. Now I want to merge the pictures together using the color mix but I do not  get desired result. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Here is an overview of my workflow:
https://goo.gl/EZklcA

Comment: @PacodeLucia Contrast enhancement of HDRI image seems like an advanced topic for a simple node tree, When I have time I will explore some algorithms and implement a solution and get back to you.